# Comment traduire « vervroegen »

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, néerlandais

Je vous demande conseil pour traduire « vervroegen ».

Le mot « renvoyer » signifie que telle ou telle rencontre sera remplacée par une autre qui aura lieu plus tard. Il me semble que le mot ne sous-entend pas de l’embêtement, sauf quand il est accompagné par « aux calendes grecques ». Je cherche le contraire de ce mot, un mot qui veut dire « remplacer une rencontre par une autre qui aura lieu plus tôt ».

Les mots *brusquer* et *bâcler* ne conviennent pas, car ils veulent dire qu’on doit agir avec peu de soin pour finir un boulot à l’heure, c’est-à-dire avant qu’une échéance soit atteinte. Ce que je cherche à exprimer ne sous-entend pas qu’il y a un travail en cours, ni qu’une échéance est proche.

Je connais aussi les mots *dépêcher*, et *hâter*. Du premier, l’emploi réfléchi est le seul qui me vient à l’esprit, et cet emploi laisse penser que quelqu’un doit parvenir au bout d’un chemin sans contretemps. Le deuxième mot m’est un peu étranger, donc j’ai besoin d’un coup de pouce pour l’utiliser avec habileté. Il y a un mot néerlandais qui parait étroitement lié, à savoir « haasten », ce qui veut dire « dépêcher ». Néanmoins, il n’en découle pas que son frère français ait le même sens.

Pensez-vous que « hâter » va bien dans ce cadre, ou y a-t-il un mot qui m’est inconnu, qui conviendrait ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pour déplacer un rendez-vous à une date ultérieure (pour qu'elle ait lieu plus tard), on dit *reporter* (pas *renvoyer*) ou *repousser*.

Pour déplacer un rendez-vous à une date antérieure (pour qu'elle ait lieu plus tôt), on dit *avancer*.

> La réunion a été reportée à la semaine prochaine.
>
> Vu l'urgence, nous voulons avancer la réunion à demain.

On ne dirait pas *hâter* pour changer une date programmée en une date plus rapprochée, mais pour signifier que quelque chose doit être fini plus rapidement. *Hâter* peut avoir une connotation qu'on fait la chose plus vite mais moins bien. « Il faut hâter la réunion » signifierait que la réunion est en cours et qu'il faut la terminer le plus vite possible.